# I have "User1" home folder, but my app looking "Default" folder, why?

Tags: c#

My winform executable calling AppData of the user directory.

Now When I am trying run my app with `User1` using below code, my app looking "Default" user directory instead of `User1` directory. What could be the reason?

> Access to path 'C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\DataFolder is denied

```
  string CommandDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Apps\";

        var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
                {
                    FileName = string.Format("{1}{0}Utility.exe", Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, CommandDirectory),
                    WorkingDirectory = string.Format("{0}", CommandDirectory),
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    UserName = "User1",
                    Password = "Password1".ToSecureString(),
                    Domain = "Machine-Name",
                },
        };

        process.Start();
```

Note - If I use `verb` and remove `UserName`, `Password`, `Domain`, then works find and looks correctly for Admin user folder,

```
UseShellExecute = false,
                    //UserName = "User1",
                    //Password = "Password1".ToSecureString(),
                    //Domain = "Machine-Name",
                    Verb = "runas"
```

Comment: Which line of code throws the `Access to path 'C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\DataFolder is denied` exception?

Comment: it's coming from utility app where I am trying to get path for user root directory. `$"{Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)}\\DataFolder\\'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you forget to set `LoadUserProfile` to `true`.

As per  [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.loaduserprofile?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> The default is false.

When you need it to be `true`.